# Android Phone Location API

Tags: android, python

I'm trying to do some home/life automation scripting and I'd like to be able to get the location of my Android phone through some API. This would be useful to do things such as turn on my home security camera, or to route my home calls to my phone if I'm away.

This would preferably a RESTful one, or an API with good Python interop.  However, I'm not averse to using any tool to get the job done.

I considered checking my router to see if my phone was connected, which will work for some things, but it would hinder me in implementing other things.

I know I could probably write an Android app that would phone home to do this, but I wanted to see if there were any alternatives first. My Google-Fu came up short on this one (if it exists).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

secrets of mobile hackers..what does google chrome use?

Google uses three approaches..the third approach is your option find a site that does or allows triangulation involving using cell tower maps..

Or lets see mobile web page to get location via google services and than hook that into your python script on the server side